# Why I do not get returned value of function of my smart contract using testRPC and a Graphical User Interface?

Tags: remix, contract-invocation, testrpc, javascript, gui

I have a smart contract that is tested with remix and it works well. Its code is as follows :

> contract Weechain:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Sample fixed supply token contract
// Enjoy. Guigs. The MIT Licence.
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import './SafeMath.sol';
import './Ownable.sol';

contract Weechain is Ownable{

  using SafeMath for uint256;

  uint256 public energyTotalSupply;
  uint256 public powerTotalSupply;

  struct Device {
    uint256 energyValue;
    uint256 powerValue;
  }
  mapping(address => Device) amount;

  event setEnergyEvent(address indexed device, uint256 energy); 
  event setPowerEvent(address indexed device, uint256 power);
  event setPayloadEvent(uint256 indexed SQN, string payload);

  // Constructor
  function Weechain() {

    energyTotalSupply = 0;
    powerTotalSupply = 0;

    amount[owner].energyValue = energyTotalSupply;
    amount[owner].powerValue = powerTotalSupply;
  }

  function amountOfenergy(address dev) constant returns (uint256 energy) {
    return amount[dev].energyValue;
  }
  function amountOfpower(address dev) constant returns (uint256 power) {
    return amount[dev].powerValue;
  }

  function setPayload(uint256 SQN, string payload) public returns (bool) {

    emit setPayloadEvent(SQN, payload);

    return true;
  }

  function setEnergy(address dev, uint256 energy) public returns(bool) {
    require(dev != address(0));

    amount[dev].energyValue = amount[dev].energyValue.add(energy);
    energyTotalSupply = energyTotalSupply.add(energy);

    emit setEnergyEvent(dev, energy);

    return true;
}

    function setPower(address dev, uint256 power) public returns (bool) {
    require(dev != address(0));

    amount[dev].powerValue = amount[dev].powerValue.add(power);
    powerTotalSupply = powerTotalSupply.add(power);

    emit setPowerEvent(dev, power);

    return true;
  }

}
```

> library SafeMath:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

library SafeMath {

  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(a == 0 || c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    // assert(b > 0); // Solidity automatically throws when dividing by 0
    uint256 c = a / b;
    // assert(a == b * c + a % b); // There is no case in which this doesn't hold
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }

  function max64(uint64 a, uint64 b) internal constant returns (uint64) {
    return a >= b ? a : b;
  }

  function min64(uint64 a, uint64 b) internal constant returns (uint64) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
  }

  function max256(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    return a >= b ? a : b;
  }

  function min256(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal constant returns (uint256) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
  }

}
```

> contract Ownable:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

contract Ownable {

  // Owner of the contract
  address public owner;

  event ChangementOwnership(address indexed _by, address indexed _to);

  function Ownable() {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }


  /// @dev Reverts if called by any account other than the owner.
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
  }

  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) external onlyOwner {
    require(newOwner != address(0));
    owner = newOwner;

    ChangementOwnership(msg.sender, newOwner);
  }

}
```

And now, I developed an HTLM / JavaScript application to interact with this smart contract as follows :

> index.html file:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Weechain Smart Contract</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

    <script src="./node_modules/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <h1>Weechain Instructor</h1>
        <p>Output: <span id="owner"></span>
        </p>
        <h2 id="instructor"></h2>

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Address</label>
        <input id="Address" type="text"> <!--name will be changed to device address-->

        <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Energy</label>
        <input id="Energy" type="text"> <!--age will be changed to energy value type = "text" will be type = "number"-->

        <button id="buttonSet">Set</button>

        <button id="buttonGet">Get</button>


    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    <script>
       if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
           web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
       } else {
           web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
       }

       web3.eth.defaultAccount = web3.eth.accounts[0];
/*
       var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_fName","type":"string"},{"name":"_age","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setInstructor","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"getInstructor","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"},{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);
*/
    var CoursetroContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"energyTotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"}],"name":"amountOfenergy","outputs":[{"name":"energy","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"powerTotalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"},{"name":"energy","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setEnergy","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"SQN","type":"uint256"},{"name":"payload","type":"string"}],"name":"setPayload","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"}],"name":"amountOfpower","outputs":[{"name":"power","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"transferOwnership","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"dev","type":"address"},{"name":"power","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPower","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"device","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"energy","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setEnergyEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"device","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"power","type":"uint256"}],"name":"setPowerEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"SQN","type":"uint256"},{"indexed":false,"name":"payload","type":"string"}],"name":"setPayloadEvent","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_by","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"}],"name":"ChangementOwnership","type":"event"}]);

       var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x39423be68bf4fb3605a7f2b846d81d301b1fd776');

       var utils = require("./utils.js");
var _ = require("lodash");
var Promise = require("bluebird");

module.exports = {
    assertEvent: function(contract, filter) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var event = contract[filter.event]();
            event.watch();
            event.get((error, logs) => {
                var log = _.filter(logs, filter);
                if (log) {
                    resolve(log);
                } else {
                    throw Error("Failed to find filtered event for " + filter.event);
                }
            });
            event.stopWatching();
        });
    }
}

       $("#buttonGet").click(function() {
       Coursetro.amountOfenergy($("#Address").val(), function(error, result) {
           if (!error) {
               $("#instructor").html(result.toString());//+' ('+result[1]+')');
               /*console.log(result.toString());
               console.log("address\tfrom\t\tto\tamount\tblockHash\tblockNumber\tevent\tlogIndex\ttransactionHash\ttransactionIndex");*/
           } else
                console.log(error);
       });

       });
/*
       $("#buttonSet").click(function() {
           //Coursetro.setPayload($("#name").val(), $("#age").val());
           Coursetro.setEnergy($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val());
           //Coursetro.setPayload($("#name").val());
       });
*/
       $("#buttonSet").click(function() {
    var estd_gas = Coursetro.setEnergy.estimateGas($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val());
    console.log(estd_gas);
    var params = {
        gas: Math.round(estd_gas * 1.25),
        from: web3.eth.accounts[0]
    };
    Coursetro.setEnergy.sendTransaction($("#Address").val(), $("#Energy").val(), params);
});

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I do step by step :

> 1. open a cmd window.
> 2. run testrpc.
> 3. copy contract address generated by **remix** into `var Coursetro = CoursetroContract.at('0x9ea9de4056ae3defda58ca02257e7b6218f2e6eb');`
>      variable.
> 4. open `index.html` and sned transaction.
>
> **However, I do not see output in HTML page.**

---

> Important Note: I used this template and tutorial : https://coursetro.com/courses/20/Developing-Ethereum-Smart-Contracts-for-Beginners/lessons/3

---

Comment: Do any error appear in the development console of your browser?

Comment: @Ismael I found the solution: converting `result` to `string`. However, i'd like to know why do we need to convert. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Just I needed to convert `result` to `string` as follows:

```
$("#instructor").html(result.toString());
```

**Note**: Honestly, I do not know what is the reason, but it works. I am interested to know why do we need to convert `result` to `string` to be shown.